# javascript Proxy get property from object

Tags: javascript

I have javascript array of objects.

I'm using Vue 3 and when trying to retrieve the `name` by `id` I don't get a good result

```
const result = this.users.find(item => item.id === 4);
console.log('result', result)

Proxy {id: 4, name: 'john doe', tasks: Array(0)}
```

But if I do so

```
console.log('result', result.name)
```

In the console log I see the following

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')

I don't even know if it matters framework Vue 3.... My be this is pure javascript.
Apparently a framework makes an object wrapper. How to get properties through the proxy object (`result.name`) ?

Comment: I'm not sure why you are using `Proxy`? The Proxy object enables you to create a proxy for another object. What do you want to achieve with the `Proxy`? And you are not using the `Proxy` object at all. How does `this.users` look like?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the proxy directly, try using it as a JSON :

```
const account = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.users.find(item => item.id === 4)));
console.log(account.name);
```

or

```
const account = JSON.stringify(this.users.find(item => item.id === 4));
console.log(account);
console.log(JSON.parse(account).name);
```